# Meteor --production not running files in client folders

Tags: meteor, client, server-side-rendering

I have a meteor app that follows this file structure, https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#example-app-structure.

In /client/main.js my code looks like this

```
import '/imports/startup/client';
console.log("this ran in client/main.js");
```

When I run `meteor`, the log shows, however, when I start the service with `meteor --production`, the log does not show.

Any idea or headings would be greatly appreciated!

FYI: This is a meteor react app with server-side rendering. Here is my package.json if it helps.

```
{
"dependencies": {
"@babel/runtime": "^7.0.0-beta.54",
"autoprefixer": "^7.1.6",
"aws-sdk": "^2.282.1",
"bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
"core-js": "^2.5.1",
"desandro-matches-selector": "^2.0.2",
"ev-emitter": "^1.1.1",
"fizzy-ui-utils": "^2.0.7",
"get-size": "^2.0.3",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"marked": "^0.3.19",
"meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.11",
"moment": "^2.21.0",
"outlayer": "^2.1.1",
"prop-types": "^15.6.1",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
"react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
"react-markdown": "^3.3.0",
"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
"s-grid": "^1.2.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {}
 }
```

Comment: It may be that the production build removes any `console.log` calls.

Comment: no, production doesn't remove console.log calls. @Junhao, where are you looking for this console output? It will appear in the browser dev console, but not in the server console. Are you perhaps looking in the wrong place? Which package are you using to do server-side rendering?

Comment: I am looking at the development console on google chrome instead of my terminal where i run the `meteor --production`. I first noticed this issue when `reactDom.hydrate()` in client/index.js did not run as there were no attached eventHandlers. I am using `react-dom` for my server-side rendering. Side note: `server/main.js`'s console output is showing in terminal (duh...)

Comment: Following up on the previous comment, I did a `meteor create --full` and tried running that with `meteor --production` and seems that nothing loads nor is logged. I was wondering if I am using meteor --production wrongly. My issue is that `ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));` does not seem to be running in production after deploying to galaxy as there are no eventHandlers attached to the DOM. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this question, I believe my usage of --production flag is not correct in evaluating why client's logs are not shown in prod vs --production vs local.